# Can not get headers and status code returned by auth_request

Tags: nginx

I have the following test nginx configuration:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log /dev/stderr debug;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    access_log  /dev/stderr  main;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    upstream content {
      server 127.0.0.1:4001;
    }

    server {
        listen 4000;
        server_name test;
        gzip off;
        autoindex off;

        location /test-auth {
            add_header X-Test "testvalue";
            return 200;
        }

        location /proxy {
            add_header "X-Test1" "test1";
            auth_request /test-auth;
            auth_request_set $test $sent_http_x_test;
            auth_request_set $test2 $upstream_status;
            add_header X-Test $test;
            add_header X-Test2 $test2;
            proxy_pass http://content?test=$test&test2=$test2;
            proxy_pass_request_body off;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 4001;
        add_header X-Test3 "test3";
        return 200 "testt response $args";
    }
}
```

I expect that requesting the `/proxy` URL will return all test headers: `X-Test` (header returned by the auth request), `X-Test1` (just a sample), `X-Test2` (value of the auth request HTTP status), `X-Test3` (set by the `content` downstream).

But in the reality, this request only returns `X-Test1` and `X-Test2`. I can not get any value (headers or return status) by the `auth_request_set` directive. I tried both variants of variable names I found in google: `$sent_http_x_test` and `$upstream_http_x_test` but no luck. The `$test` variable is always empty.

I saw the following official example: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/configuring-subrequest-authentication/ but the `auth_request_set $test2 $upstream_status;` line also doesn't work and the `$test2` variable is always empty.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `/test-auth` location has no upstream configured, you could try the configure below.

`$upstream_http_x_test` is correct.

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log /dev/stderr debug;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    access_log  /dev/stderr  main;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    upstream content {
      server 127.0.0.1:4001;
    }

    server {
        listen 4000;
        server_name test;
        gzip off;
        autoindex off;

        location /real-auth {
            add_header X-Test "testvalue";
            return 200;
        }
        
        location /test-auth {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4000/real-auth;
        }

        location /proxy {
            add_header "X-Test1" "test1";
            auth_request /test-auth;
            auth_request_set $test $upstream_http_x_test;
            auth_request_set $test2 $upstream_status;
            add_header X-Test $test;
            add_header X-Test2 $test2;
            proxy_pass http://content?test=$test&test2=$test2;
            proxy_pass_request_body off;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 4001;
        add_header X-Test3 "test3";
        return 200 "testt response $args";
    }
}
```

Comment: Why does `auth_request` require `proxy_pass` to be able to get headers and return status?

Comment: Seems that `auth_request` do not send request directlly, it looks like reading configure from `/test-auth` block. you can check the access.log, there's requests sent to `/test-auth`,  auth requests are directly sent to `/real-auth`

Comment: One of nginx contributors helped to find out the root cause: https://github.com/nginx/njs/issues/417#issuecomment-942494313 The issue is in ngx_http_headers_module. add_header is ignored for subrequest "(r != r->main)", and auth_request is a subrequest. This means that add_header is working differently when a location is directly accessed versus as a subrequest.